# Angular typescript JavaScript lexicon scope lost in nested function for third party API event handler

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scope, nested-function

I'm trying to handle an event from a third party API (ESRI ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.7).  I'm struggling with controlling scope context in an Angular component that loads the API when I try to handle and event from the ArcGIS API using their event handler callback.  Click on the map to elicit the error.  I feel like there must be a way to make this work with by controlling the context, but I haven’t been able to make it work.  Closures aren’t my strong suit.   Any help would be great.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-arcgis-api-5yfayy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fmap.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.arcgisService.loaded$.subscribe(loaded => {
      console.log("map loaded subscription");
      if(loaded) {
        this.arcgisService.constructMap({basemap: this.basemap, elevation: true}).then(map => {
          this.arcgisService.constructMapView(
            { 
            map: map,
            container: this.id,
            center: [-117.18, 34.06],
            zoom: 15
            }
            ).then(mapView => {
              console.log("constructMap.then");
              console.log(this); 
              this.mapView = mapView;
              mapView.on("click", function(event) {
                 //this.test = event.x
                 this.onMapClick(event.x)
                  console.log("click event: ", event.x);
                });
              })
        })//end construct map
      }
    })
  }

onMapClick(x){
  console.log(x)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every new function created by function statement, defined its own this value based on how the function was called. so using arrow function will refer to current object

**Try this**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.arcgisService.loaded$.subscribe(loaded => {
      console.log("map loaded subscription");
      if(loaded) {
        this.arcgisService.constructMap({basemap: this.basemap, elevation: true}).then(map => {
          this.arcgisService.constructMapView(
            { 
            map: map, 
            container: this.id,
            center: [-117.18, 34.06],
            zoom: 15
            }
            ).then(mapView => {
              console.log("constructMap.then");
              console.log(this); 
              this.mapView = mapView;
              //Use arrow function here to refer current object
              mapView.on("click", (event) => {
                 //this.test = event.x
                 this.onMapClick(event.x)
                  console.log("click event: ", event.x);
                });
              })
        })//end construct map
      }
    })
  }
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-arcgis-api-2rn4kl)

Comment: Thanks, I guess I need to get better at arrow functions.